# How to sort queries using string values of enum columns

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

my table contains int columns that correspons to enum types.
E.g. the values of int column Command corresponds to this type:

```
public enum Commands
{
  Start = 1,
  End = 2
}
```

If I query the table and order it by Command, I get the rows with Command=Start followed by Commen=End.

Is there a way I can sort the query by the string value of the Command column, e.g. End first and Start last.

results.OrderBy(s => (Command as Commands).ToString())

But it gives me error "Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported".

Of course I could put the Command's string value as a column and sort by it, but we prefer using int columns for different reasons.

Thanks

Comment: The exception does not match your code. It should be "The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type", because you can't use `as` with value types, like the enum. And: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method". Further: in EF 5 there is enum support, I'm not sure what the sorting order is, I suspect the numeric value.

Comment: It now occurs to me that you probably forgot an `s`: `s.Command`.